# i18n fallback in attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

How to use a fallback for very often used `attr_names` like `title` and `created_at`?

How it usually works:

```
activerecord.attributes.[model_name].attr_name
```

I want todo something like that:

```
activerecord.attributes.defaults.attr_name
```

There are so many examples of how to do it for the error massages, but none for the plain attributes :( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/translation.rb)'s the file containing the method which handles the translations (human_attribute_name). I think seeing this you can just do in your `lang.yml` for instance :

```
attributes:
  username: "Nickname"
```

instead of :

```
attributes:
  user:
    username: "Nickname"
```

And it should work for all models !

Comment: thanks! the path to go is `attributes.attr_name` no `activerecord` anymore for some reason :o

Comment: Because now you can use a model without a database (so without activerecord) and that's called activemodel.